# iOS - Adding view under navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I can't add a view under `UINavigationBar` (Navigation Controller), like the Facebook app. Any ideas on how I can do this?

[image]

Best,
Andrea

Comment: That "custom view" you are referring to might be a `tableHeaderView`?

Comment: @YashwantChauhan right! I had not thought about this.

Comment: Can you post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom view looks like a `tableHeaderView`. Which means you need to set your view as the `tableHeaderView`, which will then be placed on top of the tableView and underneath your navigation bar.

```
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = customView;
```